# Como modificar a largura para a adaptação em tablets de um menu sem media queries?

Tags: javascript, css, media-queries

Menu: http://responsivemultimenu.com/lib/responsive-multi-menu/

Eu nunca vi um menu responsivo como esse, não tem nada de media queries, eu acredito que a parte responsiva é criada pelo javascript. De qualquer forma este não é o meu problema, eu quero que o menu fique responsivo antes do que ele está. 
 Por exemplo, eu testei ele no resposinator  e mas ou menos em 570px o menu se modifica para se adaptar em celulares, e eu queria aumentar este numero par mais ou menos 760px.

Mas eu olhei todo o css e depois o javascript nenhum número aproximado ou parecido com esse aparece lá. 
Tem alguma tag especifica que eu deveria modificar ?

Answer (score 0):

Realmente ele utiliza javascript para fazer a troca. Calculando o espaço necessário para o menu e faz a quebra quando este valor é ultrapassado, uma maneira que encontrei de modificar isso é adicionando `padding` em `<div class="rmm style">`, assim você diminui o espaço e a troca acontece antes.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: eu não entendi muito bem, é pra colocar apenas `padding: (qualquernumero)px`  nesta parte no css: `.rmm.style` . tentei isso e nada mudou.

Answer (score 0):

Caso queira alternar o estilo de um menu sem utilizar media queries você pode utilizar a junção de css e javascript.

No css você cria uma classe para o respectivo menu relacionado a medida aproximada de 760px.

No arquivo javascript você verifica o tamanho da tela para mudar o estilo da seguinte forma:

```
if ($(window).width() <= 760 ) {

  $('.rmm').addClass('classe do css que faz o estilo para essa medida');
}
```